# Проблема с обращением к API 1C:УИТ через CURL

Tags: api, curl

Проблема с обращением к API 1C:УИТ через CURL. Просьба подсказать.

Делаю такой запрос через Postman - всё отлично.

```
*****/tasks?conditions=date > "2023-07-17T15:30:07+03"
```

Делаю запрос через CURL - выдаёт ошибку.

> " ["error"]=> string(2052) "{(30, 158)}: Операция не разрешена в
> предложении "ГДЕ" ИЛИ ДанныеОбъекта.УчастникиЗадания.Участник В
> (&СписокПользователейИГруппПользователей)) И
> ЕСТЬNULL(ОтметкиПоВремени.МоментВремени, 0) >= &МоментВремени"

Код:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '****/tasks?conditions=date > "2023-07-17T15:30:07+03"');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "Логин:Пароль");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
$responseBody = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Обращение к API от Softonit, оно гласит
"conditions - Дополнительные условия, образец delete_mark = false AND influence = "enum/influence/medium" AND project = "ref/projects/add1e365-8689-11ed-a476-001a7dda7111" OR done_date > "0001-01-01T00:00:00""
Ссылка на доку от него https://softonit.ru/api/docs/#/

При этом отлично работают через CURL обычные запросы по типу

```
****/tasks?object_start=1&object_end=15
```

Полагаю, что проблема в том, что в проблемном запросе нужны двойные кавычки..